# How to randomize the number before stopping at the lucky number. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a button that generates a random number (from 1-100) after a click. I have to make it:

- Loop through random numbers with an interval of 100ms.
- Loop stops after 10 numbers.
- Disable the button when numbers are looping.
- Enable the button when looping stops.

Not sure if I have done the code correctly, I am able to let numbers loop after click but unable to make it stop after 10 numbers. I am also unable to diable when looping and enable the button when looping stops. Appreciate your kind help. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
btn.onclick= function (){  
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);
var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
    random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);
    document.getElementById("lucky").innerHTML = "Your Lucky Number is: " + random;},100);};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Loop through random numbers with an interval of 100ms.
- Loop stops after 10 numbers. `clearInterval(interval);`
- Disable the button when numbers are looping. `btn.disabled = true;`
- Enable the button when looping stops. `btn.disabled = false;`

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('randomize');

btn.addEventListener('click', function () { 
  btn.disabled = true;
  var cpt = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      cpt++;
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);
      document.getElementById("lucky").innerHTML = "Your Lucky Number is: " + random;
      if (cpt === 10) {
        btn.disabled = false;
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
   },100);
});
```

```html
<button id="randomize">click me</button>
<div id="lucky"></div>
```